# Mysql Rollup, but with line item detail

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Maybe I am trying to do something that can't be done, as my searches don't seem to find any similar examples.

I am trying to write a query in MariaDB that lists the lineitems (detail) as well as the subtotals, totals, and grand totals.

So for instance if I have the following data:

| DonationDate | UserContactID | DonationAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-20 | 613 | 5.00 |
| 2021-05-20 | 613 | 40.00 |
| 2021-06-22 | 613 | 6.00 |
| 2021-06-22 | 613 | 10.00 |
| 2021-06-22 | 777 | 10.00 |
| 2021-06-22 | 777 | 30.00 |

| DonationDate | UserContactID | DonationAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-20 | 613 | 5.00 |
| 2021-05-20 | 613 | 40.00 |
| sub for 613 on 2021-05-20 |  | 45.00 |
| tot for 2021-05-20 |  | 45.00 |
| 2021-06-22 | 613 | 6.00 |
| 2021-06-22 | 613 | 10.00 |
| Sub for 613 on 2021-06-22 |  | 16.00 |
| 2021-06-22 | 777 | 10.00 |
| 2021-06-22 | 777 | 30.00 |
| Sub for 777 on 2021-06-22 |  | 40.00 |
| tot for 2021-06-22 |  | 56.00 |

When I try to use rollups I lose the individual lines.  For example, 2021-05-20 shows 45, not one line for 40 and the other for 5.

for example:

```
    SELECT
        DonationDate,UserContactID,DonationID, sum(DonationAmount)
    FROM
        donations 

    GROUP BY
         DonationDate, UserContactID with Rollup`
```

The first two rows show up like this:

| DonationDate | UserContactID | DonationAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-20 | 613 | 45 |
| 2021-05-20 |  | 45 |

Note that what we want is for that first 45 to show up as the detail items, 40 & 45, before showing up as as subtotal for those useids for that date.

Any help greatly appreciated. (P.S. The initial table with the data looks right on the preview, but I see it gets messed up when it actually posts.  Sorry about that.)

Comment: What mariadb version?

Comment: You need a union for this as any form of aggregation is not compatible with listing all rows.

Comment: The expected output look like a format on a web/app interface or a report. To layout the format directly from query will not be easy. There is a way to get all that subtotal by user and by date but not through `WITH ROLLUP` and the subtotal is not shown directly under the user or date but on the side as different column(s).

Comment: Yes, I can get the data I want and output as needed in php.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing an easy way to pull it essentially as I wanted it in sql, letting it do the subtotals along the way.  Thanks to all who offered suggestions.